# python: how to convert list into dictionary keys

Tags: python

Input:

```
a_list = [x,y,z,p,q,r]
value = 5
```

Output:

```
dict1 = {x: {y : {z : { p :{ q :{ r : 5}}}}}
```

Comment: How does the config file relate to the list->dict?

Answer (score 1):

Progressively construct nested dictionaries, starting with the single value:

```
from functools import reduce
dict1 = reduce(lambda d,key: {key : d}, a_list[::-1], value)
print(dict1)
#{'x': {'y': {'z': {'p': {'q': {'r': 5}}}}}}
```